# Hibernate struts 2 contradict for using multiple List type child in entity class

Tags: hibernate, struts2

Contradict for using multiple List child in entity class

I am using  Hibernate and struts 2.I am trying to populate the Entity in a form.Entity has two collection child objects.If i use List struts maps the List but hibernate gives `multibag` exception at the same time

```
Entity class
 Class College{
  Fetch lazy
  List<Employee> employees;
  Fetch lazy
  List<Student> students;

}
```

I try fetch the college details Eagarly using Fetch profiles for employees and students.
But hibernate gives exception on fetching the College details

In struts 2 form while populating college details i use college.employees[0].name

Struts maps department details in this case as it is list.

If i change employees to set it works for Hibernate but not for struts i.e employee values are not mapped

Comment: Has anybody handled this problem

Comment: please provide code as well exception, don't let people to guess your problem as everyone have limited imagination.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi have u understood the issue now

Comment: Why not mapped, doesn't it have property accessors?

Comment: @RomanC struts does not map set.

Comment: @user2229994 No, you are wrong it maps any collection.